# C++ concepts and std::cout

Tags: c++, g++, c++17, c++-concepts

In order to learn C++ concepts, i tried to recreate an EqualityComparable concept. Here is the code i wrote

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
concept bool EqualityComparable = requires(T a, T b) 
{
    {a == b};
    {a != b};
};


void foo(EqualityComparable a, EqualityComparable b)
{
    //auto t = a == b;
    //std::cout << t;  //Case 1 : This compiles
    std::cout << a == b; //Case 2 : This does not
}

int main()
{
    foo(4,2);
}
```

The idea is pretty simple, it is to have a function foo with two arguments which support operator `==` and `!=`
However when i use i try to compare `a` and `b` directly in a call to `std::cout` i get the following compiler error

> main.cpp: In instantiation of 'void foo(auto:1, auto:1) [with auto:1 = int]':
>   main.cpp:19:12:   required from here
>   main.cpp:14:20: error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'std::basic_ostream' and 'int')

as i said in the comment, if i compare a and b first and then call std::cout everything works fine. So my question i : why does gcc deduces my types to be `std::basic_ostream`and `int`in case 2 ?
I use coliru to compile the code with the following arguments

> g++ -std=c++1z -O2 -fconcepts -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out

Comment: `std::cout << (a == b);` because operator precedence, and so and so

Comment: Oh yeah of coures, silly me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the operator `<<` has higher precedence than the operator `==`

[Operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)